# EF Core migrations using asp.net core, SQL Server and Docker yields dotnet SDK error

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using Docker for Windows Version 1.13.0-rc5-beta35 (9606)

Windows 10 Pro

Visual Studio Code

---

I've created an ASP.NET Core project with Docker using the yeoman generator:

```
yo aspnet
yo docker
```

I ran into issues when I was trying to get the API to connect from a Docker container to a SQL Server instance I had running locally.

To solve this I created an instance of SQL Server running in it's own container(using the `microsoft/mssql-server-linux` image).

Both containers are running and are attached to the same user defined bridge network.

If I open a bash terminal in my asp.net core container and run the command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration
```

I was hoping that my Code First model would be created in the SQL Server instance running on the network as this is what happens when I run the setup locally (no containers).  Instead I get the below:

```
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
```

I am confused because I though dotnet had to be installed.  I've used the `microsoft/aspnetcore` as the base layer in my Dockerfile, and I can see that this in turn uses `microsoft/dotnet:1.0.3-runtime` as it's base layer...

Can someone explain why I get this message and if I'm approaching this solution in the correct way (web api and sql server in separate containers)?
If I do need to install the dotnet sdk, I would appreciate if someone could show me how to do that as part of a Dockerfile

Thanks for any help

---

**Contents of asp.net core Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/publish /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:3000
EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash -c "dotnet MyAppName.dll"
```

Answer (score 2):

`microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1.0` your are using is based on `microsoft/dotnet:1.1.0-runtime`. It contains only .NET Core runtime, not SDK. To execute commands like `run`, `ef` and other tools - you need [one of `sdk`-based images](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore-build/)